# Is there a way to force the user inside a html text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Id like to know if anyone has a suggestion for forcing a user to select a text box with Javascript/Jquery?

Example: user clicks X object on web page. User is forced into a text box in which they should enter information first.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes. The `focus` of the field

Comment: @quirimmo Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :)

Comment: no pb :) added an answer with both the snippets, using jquery and plain js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is called `focus`.

Here the examples using jquery and plain js:

```js
function setFocusjquery() {
  $('#text-1').focus();
}

function setFocus() {
  document.querySelector('#text-2').focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="setFocusjquery()">FOCUS jquery</button>
<input type="text" id="text-1" />
<br />
<button onclick="setFocus()">FOCUS JS</button>
<input type="text" id="text-2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener to your event trigger object with,

### Native JavaScript

```
let myXObject = document.getElementById('#xObject');
let myTextbox = document.getElementById('#myTextbox');
myXObject.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myTextbox.Focus();
});
```

### JQuery

```
let myXObject = $('#xObject');
let myTextbox = $('#myTextbox');
myXObject.click(function() {
    myTextbox.focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript `focus()` method.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="focusField()">Click me</button>

...

<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

JavaScript:

```
function focusField() {
    document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
}
```